# Handling double quotes in mailto:

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.net.. I want to preview email that is created in the web page. I have problems in handling double quotes in the email body.

```
string emailbody = "\"some text\"";

btPreviewEmail.OnClientClick = "javascript:location.href='mailto:?subject=Chalk Pushcast Software Order Agreement&body=" + emailbody + "';";
```

I have left the recipient's field blank because I just have to preview the email.

At runtime, I get a Microsoft Outlook error like,
"The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you need to put them on the url, so you can simply URL encode them (to `%22`):

```
string emailbody = "%22some text%22";
```